# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Installation Failure on HP CE 1000Tu Laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, acpi

My new Laptop HP Pavilion 14 CE1000Tu came preloaded with Windows 10. I wanted Ubuntu and Windows so used the Windows disk management console to set around 80GB for Ubuntu. The problem is I am not able to try Ubuntu or Install it.
I keep getting ACPI Error that says parse failed then it goes to the Ubuntu screen and again comes back to the error screen saying ACPI Error(Bug) parse failed.
I disabled secure boot and tried but I am not able to install or even use Ubuntu Live both seem to fail.

Below are my partitions.
[image]

I have updated my BIOS to the latest version as well but does not seem to change the result.

Here is the exact message displayed to me
[image]

Comment: Did you try different USB sticks or different USB ports ?

Comment: I've encountered a similar issue few times, in this number yesterday too. What is working for me is to install **18.04.1** and then just do `apt update && apt upgrade`.

Comment: @UgurAkgul I will try a different port. I have not tried a different USB stick but I have checked the current one is working fine.

Comment: @pa4080 Will try what you said after trying out akgul's ssuggestion

Comment: @AAB USB sticks that work fine in general usage may not work for this purpose. But whatever stick you try make  sure you're booting it in UEFI mode. The ACPI errors aren't that relevant at first glance but what comes after certainly is.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Hi Ubuntu 18.04.1 installs fine after showing the same error screen for a few seconds. Ubuntu is running fine now with Windows 10 alongside. The Grub loader takes a while. My Laptop screen remains black for 1 or 2 seconds and then I can see the boot menu any idea why?

Comment: @pa4080 Ubuntu 18.04.1 installed fine ( even Pop OS works fine, Not using it cause Windows won't show up in its boot menu). I see a small delay maybe 1 or 2 seconds before I see grub the screen is blank/black never had this issue before. My Old HP P073tx laptop showed the grub menu way faster will updating to 18.04.2 make things faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To any souls still facing issues, If you are using rufus to create the bootable drive then please use "DD mode" when asked. The issue I faced happened on Linux Mint as well and using DD mode fixed it for both Ubuntu and Linux Mint.